# External Drive, can't empty trash, rm sees a file, but ls -la doesn't

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, high-sierra

I was clearing a music folder in my external drive and found a directory I can't delete no matter what I try.

**If I put it in trash bin via GUI**

> The operation can’t be completed because the item “folder” is in use.

**If I use `rm -rf` to remove it via terminal**

```
$ rm -rf folder/
rm: folder/: Directory not empty
```

**If I use `ls -la` to check its content**

```
$ ls -la
total 512
drwxrwxrwx  1 user  staff  131072 Jan  3  2017 .
drwxrwxrwx  1 user  staff  131072 Jan  3  2017 ..
```

**If I use `rm -i *` within the folder**

```
$ rm -i *
rm: 03 - Ēlusion.mp3: No such file or directory
```

**If I use `sudo lsof +D folder/` to check if any files are opened**

Nothing returns on program exit.

**If I use Disk Utility to repair (first aid) disk and volume**

Health check passed so no repair was initiated.

**If I reboot macOS**

The issue persists.

**Additional info:**

- I can move the folder within the drive, but not to another drive.
- I can rename the folder.
- `ls -i *.mp3` returns `ls: 03 - Ēlusion.mp3: No such file or directory`, same as `rm -i *.mp3`.
- The file doesn't show up in Finder, that's confusing part, whatever filename display issue Terminal could have (I always set it to use `Unicode - UTF-8`), I think there are more force at play.

**In response to questions, nope, `ls -ib` doesn't return anything.**

```
$ ls -i
$ ls -ib
$ ls -laib
total 512
2762318 drwxrwxrwx  1 user  staff  131072 Jan  3  2017 .
2685260 drwxrwxrwx  1 user  staff  131072 Jan  3  2017 ..
```

---

So apparently there is *something* in it but `ls -la` couldn't see it, while `rm -i` is being weird with filename?

`get info` via GUI context menu did confirm there is 1 item in the folder, but with zero byte, and certainly doesn't show up in finder.

I am not sure what to do at this point. Help much appreciated!

(Using 10.13.4 + ExFAT on external drive)

Comment: Have you considered backing up all the stuff you want  - probably already backed up anyway... then completely re-formatting that drive to start over?

Comment: Does `ls -b` show the file? If so, you can `ls -bi` to get the inode and follow the below answer, or alternately just copy the filename in the `-b` output.

Comment: I believe the core problem is not with filename, `ls -bi *.mp3` show the same result as shown in OP.

Answer (score 11):

The problem appears to be caused by a file named **03 - Ēlusion.mp3** located within the directory named **folder**.

Because Terminal.app is unable to render diacritical marks in file names--well, it is, but that's beyond the scope of providing the simplest solution for you--it hides its failure by hiding the filename (something unheard of by me before now; perhaps its High Sierra's changes to /.file, /.volfs and 64-bit inodes? Wait-- never mind; your edit to your question tell me I misunderstood you.) Anyway, the file's existence is known, along with the ironical contention by the Finder that it doesn't exist. Obviously, it does. Here's how to change that:

First, determine the file's inode number. In Terminal.app, `cd` to the directory "folder" and issue this command: `ls -i *.mp3`

Copy the number string of the inode provided in the left-hand column of the response, which will be something like

`12345678  03 - E ̄lusion.mp3`

--and put it into this command, which will rename it to something the terminal can render correctly:

`find . -inum 12345678 -exec mv {} deletemenow \;`

--giving you the file "deletemenow" in the folder "folder," both of which you may dispose of in whatever way best suits your fancy.

Comment: Wow, that's an impressively terrible bug.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate. The terminal may hide _single characters_ that it cannot render, but it will not remove the entire line of text.

Comment: @duskwuff Either way it seems that filename is causing issues, so this is a potential solution regardless.

Comment: Sorry but the issue seem more complex than this: I tried `$ ls -i *.mp3`, it returns
`ls: 03 - Ēlusion.mp3: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Ah, unfortunate. Well, since A.) Attempting to place the directory named "folder" in the Trash results instead in a warning that the item is "in use" B.) That the file therein is reported as being 0 bytes in length (it's already been erased--mostly), and C.) that the external drive is formatted Ex-Fat, I'd say the next simple solution would be to attach the drive to a Windows computer and try the obvious approaches once the volume has mounted. Well, it's simple if you have ready access to a Windows computer, that is...

Comment: Can you just run `ls -i` within the directory to prevent the shell wildcard expansion from interfering?

Comment: @nohillside sure, and it returns absolutely nothing, even with `ls -ib`, I will update the question.

Comment: @DocG. yeah will try windows one day...

Comment: @duskwulff -- I would have said exactly the same thing some months ago, and having just seen the edit made to the original question I will now again agree with you--I thought at the time of writing my answer that no file name meant I was seeing some APFS fallout such as here: https://eclecticlight.co/2017/04/05/file-problems-in-ios-10-3-and-macos-10-13-whats-in-a-name/ and here: https://eclecticlight.co/2017/04/06/untangling-file-names-and-normalisation-with-apfelstrudel/

Comment: Alright, I have tested this with Windows 10, and yep it worked, mp3 file is shown and has its original byte count (I can play too). I got curious and copy/rename the same file with a name like `test.mp3`. And it shows in macOS finder/terminal correctly. I am going to pin this to an exFAT compatibility issue on macOS.

Comment: I am not sure if you want to edit your answer or I should submit one myself :)

Comment: You go ahead... you didn't need my comment about "the next simple solution" to come up with the idea of hooking up a computer whose native filesystem matches the one on your external drive..

Comment: Wait.. What? The file's INTACT? Heh. Shades of `dot_clean`. Does the phrase "Error 36" ring a bell? No, don't answer that; water under the bridge. Consider, though, editing the headline in your post to include "exFAT Drive" to help those with similar issues.

Comment: @Doc G. I have another explanation, but it will take me 5 minutes to do a quick writeup, hold on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80106/discussion-between-doc-g-and-bitinn).

Answer (score 9):

***It took me a long time to come to this summary, but I think it's the definitive answer.***

The cause of my issue is [a well-known one](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2165#issuecomment-134233582):

> OS X is the odd one out, both in that it normalizes file names and in that [it uses NFD instead of the more common NFC](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/).

Historically (not that old, pre 10.11 era), [OS X + HFS+ enforces NFD form on all filenames](https://www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/man/#HFS-on-OS-X-Darwin), and you will only get NFD result from commands and system calls.

Then things starts to change, in 10.11, [some system call results are normalized to NFC](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2165#issuecomment-121663632), which puts it inline with Windows and Linux, but at the expense of breaking some programs that expect NFD on OS X.

But since the introduction of macOS 10.13 + AFPS, the behavior changes again: Apple decides it wants to [normalize to NFD on display and system calls](https://www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/man/#APFS-on-macOS), but leave the original filenames as it is (so both NFC and NFD are supported, but if you select the filename in Finder or copy `ls` result in Terminal, you get NFD form).

**This is all great, until you put a file with NFD filename in an external drive using exFAT** (as it's the only cross-macOS/Windows format with 4GB+ file size support): **macOS 10.13 somehow believe your file must be in NFC format, so it bugged out.**

In fact, here is a quick test, I have a folder in Windows on my exFAT drive with 3 files:

[image]

- `test.mp3`
- `Ēlusion.mp3` (`Ē` in NFC)
- `03 - Ēlusion` (`Ē` in NFD)

(You can copy [the exact unicode here](https://mothereff.in/html-entities#E%CC%84lusion%0A%C4%92lusion))

When I mount them on my macOS, this is what I see:

[image]

and `ls -laib` result:

```
$ ls -laib
total 46592
2762318 drwxrwxrwx  1 user  staff    131072 Jan  3  2017 .
2685260 drwxrwxrwx  1 user  staff    131072 Jan  3  2017 ..
1572961 -rwxrwxrwx  1 user  staff  11672464 Aug 23  2014 Ēlusion.mp3
1572871 -rwxrwxrwx  1 user  staff  11672464 Aug 23  2014 test.mp3
```

**As you can see, the NFC file is present but NFD file is missing.**

Even if you are aware of the [NFC/NFD problem on OS X](https://library.panic.com/transmit/transmit5/text-composition/), you might not expect exFAT external drive to face this issue in the opposite way (NFC is fine, but NFD is pant-on-fire).

But what could have caused my music file to use NFD filename in the first place:

- I originally downloaded this music file on 10.9/10.10 with an older Mac, which enforces NFD filename.
- At some point I move them away to a Windows + NTFS drive, which doesn't enforce NFC/NFD, so original NFD filename is preserved.
- Now I want to move this file back to my macOS 10.13 + APFS using an exFAT drive (exFAT supports the same UTF-16 convention as NTFS).
- Hell break loose.

I could have copied the file via networked drive or TeamViewer, and it would be fine, but exFAT is triggering this bug on macOS.

**Lessons:**

- Unicode filename is still a threat.
- You actually need an Windows/Linux to fix this issue (if the situation is your file are on an exFAT external drive).

Comment: @bitlinn: Click on the second link in my comment addressed to duskwulff and try out the Apfelstrudel unicode normalisation tool you'll find there. Very useful for APFS, pointless with exFAT. Or is it...?

Comment: @DocG. this issue is a bit more complex than I initially thought, but I have updated my answer, again!

Comment: Yeah, I thought you might end up doing that. See my earlier comment about `Error 36` and do a web search for something like "move files back and forth windows mac error 36" for more information on separating file attributions on non-HFS systems. This has been (another) known MacOS / OS X file naming problem since System 10.6 arrived. Between the Unicode normalisation and the dot_underscore attribute separation, you experienced a heck of a double bug. I doubt if the dot_clean command stood a chance.